# Remove all CSS classes named like a given pattern?

Tags: jquery

Is there a simple way to remove a class from an element when I don't know the exact class name (only a prefix)?

At first this might sound strange so I give an example to clarify: a Bootstrap button may have `btn-primary` xor `btn-success` xor `btn-danger` xor ... applied. I want to remove this class (whichever it is) and apply a new one.

Currently I have:

```
let btnClasses = [ 'btn-primary', 'btn-success', ... ];
$.each(btnClasses, function(i, x) {
    $(myElem).removeClass(x);
});
```

I'd love to have something alike:

```
$(myElem).removeClass('btn-*');
```

Is there a built-in way to do so?

Comment: Great catch! Must have used the wrong search terms. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could write your own plugin for jQuery. It would be named differently but it's one way.

```js
$.fn.removeClassRegex = function (pattern) {
  var element = $(this);
  var classNames = element.attr('class').split(' ');
  $(classNames).each(function (key, value) {
    if (value.match(pattern)) {
      element.removeClass(value);
    }
  });
}

$('div').removeClassRegex('test-[a-z]');
console.log($('div').attr('class'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test-bar foo">
</div>
```

Comment: A good alternative - thank you for your effort - upvoted! Still, personally, I'm going to use the built-in way as described in the linked duplicate.

Comment: Yeh, just read that answer and it is a much better solution